# Firemonkey ScrollBox editing at Design time

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, design-time, scrollbars

I'm designing an application in Firemonkey and some of the controls are inside a scrollbox.
Is there a way to edit the content of the part outside the Scrollbox's displayed area, by moving somehow the scrollbars at DesignTime?

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same experience. The only way I can make the scroll box scroll in design mode is by using the mouse wheel. If it weren't for that, I don't know how a person could design outside the viewable portion of the scroll box. Is that what you do currently?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can't *directly* do that (because the scrollbars are not exposed in the prop. inspector). It seems that the only way would be to select the object you want to edit inside the structure tree and then to set its properties, such as the position, in the inspector.

Alternatively you could create a ScrollBox descendant and publish the scrollbars (with **stored** set to false) so that their values can be changed at design-time.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer.. I'm going for the non visual approach, by editing properties in the Object Inspector, until it will become unmanageable... Then I will switch to the other method

Answer (score 0):

You should use the Custom Device option, and resize the view.

Answer (score 0):

May be it's too late for answering.
But you may add all of your controls inside a trectangle and then in structure panel drag that rectangle to make it  scrollbox's child.
change the position of trectangle to (0, 0);
now you can change rectangle's position to see other controls which is not
accessible through display area.
Check these pictures

[image: See Picture1 with position.y:= 0]
[image: See Picture2 with position.y:= -80]